# How do i removed SchemaReferenceHandling in NjsonSchema

Tags: c#, .net, json, jsonschema, njsonschema

I am working on Generating JSON Schema from .NET type using NJsonSchema.
I am getting references("$ref"...) for complex type in the generated json.

```
"properties": {
    "resourceType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "onset": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "recorder": { 
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ResourceReference"
    },
```

I do not want references , instead i want entire block here itself.
I have tried  below line of code but it does-not seems to be working.

```
var generator = new NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator(new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings { AllowReferencesWithProperties = false });
```

I was able to do this by using Newtonsoft.Json package(see below code), but Newtosoft.Json had limitation of 10 schema generation per hour , i had to switch to NJsonSchema.

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator { SchemaReferenceHandling = SchemaReferenceHandling.None };
```

Is there any way i can have the entire block and not have it referenced using NJsonSchema.

Comment: Why not just manually copy the ResourceReference reference into the place where you want it to be?

Comment: Its more that 3000 line Json file which is being generated from number of .Net classes.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @CageE NjsonSchema does not support this as of now , the owner has marked this requirement as enhancement. You can track it here https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/642